# Combobox; Show Different Description Text Upon Selection?

Tags: javascript, html, combobox

This is a sample code.

If we have 100 options e.g. and User selects an Option it shows the respective Description.

I made it work with Jscript but thats too long code to mess around. and  is simple thing

Here is JS Version : http://jsfiddle.net/eHwVn/

and I want to Use Simple HTML

```
<select>
  <option value="i">ItemA</option>
  <option value="i">ItemB</option>
  <option value="i">ItemC</option>
  <option value="i">ItemD</option>
  <option value="i">ItemE</option>
  <option value="i">ItemF</option>
</select>
```

How to add description to each item using HTMl?

TO Get this:

(Sorry I cant post Images Yet)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSm4j.png

Thanks for Help

Peace!

Comment: **Check This Fiddle Please: http://jsfiddle.net/H9McM/1/**

Answer (score 0):

Try the following JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3XTjH/

using the HTML :

```
<select id="example" onchange="showtext()">
    <option value="http://www.cnet.com" data_info="Click here for Cnet, the primer technology site on the net!">Cnet</option>
    <option value="http://www.cnn.com" data_info="Click here for CNN, one of the best sources online to get your news.">CNN</option>
    <option value="http://www.geocities.com" data_info="Click here for Geocities, and receive 10 megs of free web space.">Geocities</option>
</select>
<br>
<textarea rows=5 cols=21 wrap="virtual" id="text"></textarea>
```

and the Javascript :

```
function showtext() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("example");
    var curOption = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex];

    var info = curOption.getAttribute('data_info');

    var txt = document.getElementById('text');

    txt.value = info;
}
```

Every time you select a new option it find the currently selected option, and then find the value of the `data_info` attribute of that option and set the value of the text area to it.

Comment: Thanks alot Pal! But this one sounds easier to me (http://jsfiddle.net/m2fQ3/) can you help me to show the answer of First option on load?